# Bootstrap Dropdown - Display selection within dropdown button and store in database

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to achieve 2 things:

1. Display in the dropdown button the text of which selection the user has made.
2. I want to be able to save this selection to a variable as I want to store in in a database when the form is submitted.

Code: Here is what I attempted to get the text to display in the button.

```
  <p>What group does the event belong to? </p>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select a category
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">6</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    <br>


    <script>

    <!--This code is to get the button to display the selected field-->

    $('.caret').on('click', function(){
        $('.dropdown-menu li').val($(this).text());
    });


    </script>
```

Could anyone help with either or both aims?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this script should do what you want.

```
$(function() {
    var selectedOption;

    $('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(){
        selectedOption = $(this).text();
        $('button.btn').html(selectedOption);
    });    
})
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry if I was unclear but you do understand correctly, I want the selected option to appear as the text on the button rather than 'select a category' This code does not seem to work though.

Comment: I've modified the code so it should replace the code in the button now. 
The code is working for me. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: My bad, it works, thanks!:)